# Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump to the "Search bookmarks" field in Chrome's Bookmark Manager?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarks

Muscle memory has me pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but that of course opens up Chrome's find functionality, which is not what I'm looking for here.

Is there any other way, to focus on the search field, rather than mouse-click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a default shortcut that can do that but there are some options:

1. [*Input Cursor Focus*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/input-cursor-focus/hnhplmcglkomfmoapojflionoibodhla?hl=en)  chrome extension
2. *Vimium* chrome extension. It uses the vim Linux text editor keys to navigate on a page. But I don't think that will work with Chrome bookmark manager
3. Change the Tab key settings to focus only on text fields
4. <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to reload the page. Google bookmark manager automatically focuses on the search text field

Comment: Thanks!  #4 is a really clever solution that should do the trick for me.  Regarding #1, do you have a link to this extension?

Comment: @A.Ro updated answer with the link

Comment: [1] Link is broken (404)... :-(

Comment: @VanJone Replaced with a different extension. Vimium usually does the trick for me on any page other than Bookmarks by pressing `gi`. On bookmark manager, I use #4 which is simple.